# query forming issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute the following query in oracle but not able to form it here
 `user_id = 561 in x1_table`. The query looks  like

```
delete from x1_table where id in (select id from y1_table where actual_id=123 )
and user_id of x1_table should not be a part of select owner_id from y1_table
```

Comment: What about replace IS with IN?

Comment: ya it was a typo while posting

Comment: @harqs : take a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    delete x from x1_table x 
    where x.user_id = 123 and
    x.id in (select id from y1_table where actual_id = 123 ) and 
    x.user_id not in ( select owner_id from y1_table );
```

Since we have column 'id' common in both the tables we can frame query using join

```
    delete x from x1_table x join y1_table y
    on x.id = y.id
    where x.user_id = 789 and
    y.actual_id = 123 and
    x.user_id != y.owner_id;
```

Comment: this is fine but how shall i pass the x.user_id ?

Comment: You can't frame the delete using a `join`. Oracle does not accept this syntax. You can't use `delete x` it's `delete from`, otherwise you're mostly correct.